# Change the date of file versions stored on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I need to change the date of changes made in Dropbox files.

For example: File uploaded on 2/9/20 and modified on 8/9/20.

There are now two versions of the file.

I would need two things:

1. Delete the original version.
2. Change the modified date to — for example — 10/10/20.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
If the file is by itself, not in an archive such as Zip or Tar, the last modified date becomes that when downloaded; DropBox does not preserve that date, AFAIK.

However, if the file is inside an archive,

- Delete the original file on DropBox.
- [Change](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/) the *last modified date* of the file on your PC.
- Replace the file in the archive with the new one.
- Upload the archive to DropBox.